# In SPSS software, variable view disappears after changing data type from string to numeric

Tags: spss

After the import of my .xls data into SPSS software, I change String variables to Numeric Continuous and they disappear from viewing.

How to fix that?

Thank you

Comment: This isn't really appropriate for Stack Overflow, as this is a programming site.  I'm not sure what would be more appropriate - [SU] or [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/). perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that in SPSS, the whole variable will be erased. To get the numeric variable, use the syntax:

```
recode StringVar (convert) into NumericFVar.
execute.
```